# Powershell script to rename by parent directory and increment thereafter

Tags: powershell, loops, directory, rename, parent

I am trying to count the number of files in a directory and then rename the files by parent folder. The first file will be .extension and every file after will be .extension. This is what I have so far:

```
$RootDir = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is the root directory?'
        $grabFiles = Get-ChildItem $RootDir -Filter *.txt-recurse 

#count the number of pst files in directory recursively
        $fileNum = (Get-ChildItem $grabFiles | Measure-Object).Count 

#Gather parent directory 
        $parent = Resolve-Path . | Split-Path -Leaf  


        for($x=0; x -lt $fileNum; $x++)


        #loop to rename file recursively 
        #starting by <ParentDirectory> for the first file then <ParentDirectoy>1...2...3... for every other file

            {
            if($x -lt 1){
            $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $parent".pst" -Verbose
            }
            else
            {
                $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $parent + $x".pst" -Verbose
            }
            }
```

Comment: ...and your question is?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your trying to do? It should work recursively as well

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\User1\Temp\testdir
$Count = 1

foreach ($txt in $Files)
{
    Rename-Item -Path $txt.FullName -NewName ($txt.Directory.Name + $count + ".pst") -Verbose
    $Count++
```

Alternative. if we start our count from 0 we can the remove the 0 from the name after the loop

```
$Path  = "C:\Users\User1\Temp\testdir"
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path 
$Count = 0

foreach ($txt in $Files)
{
    Rename-Item -Path $txt.FullName -NewName ($txt.Directory.Name + $count + ".pst") -Verbose
    $Count++
}

Rename-Item -Path ($path + $txt.Directory.Name + 0 + ".pst" ) -NewName ($path + $txt.Directory.Name + ".pst" )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for the most part. How can I make the first variable just the directory name and every other file increments?

Comment: Curently my example names the files tesdir1.pst,testdir2.pst etc. Are you trying to name the first testdir.pst and the second testdir1.pst

Comment: that's exactly what i'm trying to do

Comment: Edited the answer.  just renaming the first file after the loop.